# How can I let Athena supports gzip file from s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am streaming Cloudtrail logs to s3 bucket but the file format is `gz` which looks like `ACCOUNT_ID/_CloudTrail_ap-northeast-3_20220713T0545Z_bMwCXb006JPhiUvN.json.gz`. I setup a Athena table to load the file from this bucket but I can't see any data by querying them from Athena.

The table in Athena was created by below code. The columns in the table is standard format from cloudtrail event.

I suspect the reason I can't see any data is that the file format is `gz` not `json`. Is there a way to support querying gz file in Athena?
Another question is where I can see the streaming logs in Athena. I believe there must be many errors happens there.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE cloudtrail_dynamodb_access_logs (
eventversion STRING,
useridentity STRUCT<
               type:STRING,
               principalid:STRING,
               arn:STRING,
               accountid:STRING,
               invokedby:STRING,
               accesskeyid:STRING,
               userName:STRING,
sessioncontext:STRUCT<
attributes:STRUCT<
               mfaauthenticated:STRING,
               creationdate:STRING>,
sessionissuer:STRUCT<  
               type:STRING,
               principalId:STRING,
               arn:STRING, 
               accountId:STRING,
               userName:STRING>>>,
eventtime STRING,
eventsource STRING,
eventname STRING,
awsregion STRING,
sourceipaddress STRING,
useragent STRING,
errorcode STRING,
errormessage STRING,
requestparameters STRING,
responseelements STRING,
additionaleventdata STRING,
requestid STRING,
eventid STRING,
resources ARRAY<STRUCT<
               ARN:STRING,
               accountId:STRING,
               type:STRING>>,
eventtype STRING,
apiversion STRING,
readonly STRING,
recipientaccountid STRING,
serviceeventdetails STRING,
sharedeventid STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY (region string, year string, month string, day string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.amazon.emr.hive.serde.CloudTrailSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.amazon.emr.cloudtrail.CloudTrailInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://aws-cloudtrail-logs-ACCOUNT_ID-7c5d98f0/AWSLogs/Account_ID/CloudTrail/';
```

Comment: Amazon Athena will automatically handle .gz files. There is likely something else wrong with the DDL. I normally go to **AWS Glue** and **create a crawler**. I point it to my data and it automatically creates a table based on the files it sees. Give it a try!

Comment: thanks I will try glue. But if there is something wrong, where I can see the error logs?

Comment: Is there a "/" in the filename of the logs? If so, it will affect the LOCATION as it will be concidered a partition. Try to only add the bucket name in the LOCATION without any partitions

Comment: The above statement is auto generated in Athena console when I choose cloudtrail event type. I believe it is a correct format